# Mysql REGEXP_REPLACE in wp_postmeta

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace

I'm trying to replace empty alt img (alt="") in wordpress wp_post_meta table.
The idea is to replace empty alt with the image name that is placed right before the empty alt.

I have something like this in meta_value column:

```
src="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/image_name.jpg" alt=""
```

I wrote this regex, which works ok in targeting the image name:

```
[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]* alt="")
```

How can I use this regex in a query to effectively replace the content?
I've tried with something like this, but with no success:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
set meta_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(meta_value,'alt=""','/[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]* alt="")/gm');
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The second argument to `REGEXP_REPLACE()` is the regular expression. Why do you have it in the 3rd argument?

Comment: You don't have to put `//` around the regular expression in MySQL. Flags go in the 6th argument, not at the end of the regexp. Have you read the documentation at [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)?

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE()` doesn't have back-references so you can't copy part of the match into the replacement. You need to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to get the name before `alt`, then concatenate that into the replacement string yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it following these steps:

- extract your image name with a [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr)
- insert your image name between the double quotes using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(meta_value, 
                                '(?<=alt=")(?=")',
                                REGEXP_SUBSTR(meta_value, '[^\/]+(?=\.[^\/.]* alt="")'));
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/PwrW7BzuEzTQmQ5s685BC/1).